# Use Bootstrap Button Group to Swap Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, woocommerce

I'm creating a login / register form for a woocommerce shop.

The default woo template shows two side by side forms, one for new customers to register, one for existing customers to login. IMHO this sucks.

I want to use a button group above a single form that swaps out the login / register forms based on the users selection, this way only one option is presented at a time. Hence, I need to swap content, and apply/remove active classes to the appropriate buttons.

I've done the following:

1.) Added a twitter bootstrap button-group like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" id="login_click" class="btn btn-default active" data-toggle="button">Login</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" id="register_click" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.) Wrapped the two forms in bootstrap classes and added IDs for simple targeting.

```
<div id="login_form" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
 // login form
</div>

<div id="register_form" clas="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
//register form
</div>
```

I know there are [built in jQuery plugins](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) for accomplishing this. I've tried using the `.active` class without success. I also tried using `data-toggle="button"` and use the `.toggle()` method without success. I can't wrap my head around the appropriate jQuery, I either end up with both buttons toggled, or no buttons toggled.

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not just use the the nav-tabs or nav-pills?  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#tabs

Comment: Looking this over more, I'd have to agree with @jme11 that you should just use Bootstrap tabs with nav-pills. Here's a version I styled to style the nav-pills like a button-group: http://jsfiddle.net/9H2gL/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested I made it work. Not the "bootstrap way" but it works as desired. Someone with better jQuery chops could certainly simplify this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var login_btn = $('#login_click');
    var register_btn = $('#register_click');
    var register_form = $('#registration_form'); 
    var login_form = $('#login_form');

    // set defaults 
    register_form.addClass("hidden");
    login_btn.addClass("active");

    // events for register button
    register_btn.on("click", function(){
        login_form.addClass("hidden");
        login_btn.removeClass("active");
        register_btn.addClass("active");
        register_form.removeClass("hidden");
    });
    //events for login button
    login_btn.on("click", function(){
        register_form.addClass("hidden");
        register_btn.removeClass("active");
        login_btn.addClass("active");
        login_form.removeClass("hidden");       
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set some jQuery to hide/show the form divs:

```
$('#switch-forms .btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#switch-forms .btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('#login_click').on('click', function() {
    $('#register_form').hide();
    $('#login_form').show();
});
$('#register_click').on('click', function() {
    $('#login_form').hide();
    $('#register_form').show();
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezrafree/HZbvA/

Also, you misspelled the `class` attribute on `button#register_click`. Updated markup is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div id="switch-forms" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" id="login_click" class="btn btn-default active">Login</button>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" id="register_click" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="login_form" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <p>Login Form</p>
    </div>

    <div id="register_form" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <p>Register Form</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close but the class isn't removed from the login button the first run through. I think I remember using preventDefault for this, I'll give it a shot. It's also worth noting that the default state is for the login form to be shown and the login button to be depressed. TY.

Comment: Ah thank you, getting closer, but the buttons are now both active if I try to reveal the register form. I didn't even notice the class misspell and the browser was able to figure it out so it didn't affect anything.

Comment: Here's another jsfiddle using rockTheWorld's answer below, but still setting the active class on the buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/ezrafree/9H2gL/

Comment: That answer is as close as it gets but still not right. Both buttons perform the same function.

Answer (score 0):

**Code updated**
No jQuery, you could do it with bootstrap collapse.
try this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="login_click" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".class1">Login</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="register_click" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".class1">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div  class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
<div class="class1 collapse in">123</div>
<div class="class1 collapse">321</div>
        </div>
```

cannot comment in feed. there right way to use toggleClass
not good

```
$('#switch-forms .btn').on('click', function() {
$('#switch-forms .btn').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

good

```
$('#switch-forms .btn').on('click', function() {
$('#switch-forms .btn').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: That simple stacked the buttons. By wrapping each button in its own div it places them sidebar side, creating more of a toolbar effect, which is the style I want. What I'm looking for is some guidance on jQuery, I believe everything else is setup correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am sorry, missunderstood question. If I understand right - code should help you. I updated it.

Comment: Thats a creative solution but it creates unexpected behavior. If you click the same button twice it swaps the forms. It also does have the login button depressed by default, which is a requirement. There is built in functionality for this in Bootstrap, I just can't seem to make it work. I'm surprised I couldn't find this on SO, seems like a common pattern for login / register forms.

Comment: Use  Ezra Free solution but use toggleClass to avoid redundant code.

Comment: Will have to go with that but would be nice to have a definitive thread here on how to accomplish this with bootstrap methodology.

Comment: Sry I have forgotten. You can use data-toggle=' tab' and jQuery for activating btns http://jsfiddle.net/9H2gL/2/